# ZK how to stop OnClick event of tab?

Tags: events, onclick, tags, zk

I am creating dynamic `tabs`. I have created `1st` tab then `2nd` tab etc. When I am at `3rd` tab, I want the user not to be able to select the other tabs, or in other words, user will not be able to move from one tab to other tabs.

I am using `event.propagation();` to stop the event but it is not working. Does anyone have other solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

zul

```
<zk>
    <div apply="test.TestComposer">
        <tabbox>
            <tabs id="tbs" />
            <tabpanels id="tps" />
        </tabbox>
        <button id="btn" label="add tab" />
    </div>
</zk>
```

TestComposer.java

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.*;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.SelectorComposer;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.annotation.Listen;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.annotation.Wire;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.util.Clients;
import org.zkoss.zul.Button;
import org.zkoss.zul.Label;
import org.zkoss.zul.Tab;
import org.zkoss.zul.Tabpanel;
import org.zkoss.zul.Tabpanels;
import org.zkoss.zul.Tabs;

/**
 * Tested with ZK 6.0.2 and ZK Pivottable 2.0.0
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class TestComposer extends SelectorComposer {
    @Wire
    Button btn;
    @Wire
    Tabs tbs;
    @Wire
    Tabpanels tps;
    List tabs = new ArrayList();
    int limit = 3;

    @Listen("onClick = #btn")
    public void onClick$btn () {
        if (tabs.size() < limit) {
            Tab tab = new Tab("Tab " + (tabs.size()+1));
            tab.setParent(tbs);
            tabs.add(tab);
            Tabpanel tp = new Tabpanel();
            new Label("Tabpanel " + tabs.size()).setParent(tp);
            tp.setParent(tps);

            if (tabs.size() == limit) {
                tab.setSelected(true);
                overrideBehavior();
            }
        }
    }
    public void overrideBehavior () {
        final Tab toSel = (Tab)tabs.get(tabs.size()-1);
        for (int i = 0; i < tabs.size() - 1; i++) {
            final Tab tab = (Tab)tabs.get(i);
            tab.addEventListener( // add an EventListener
                    "onClick", // listen to onClick event
                    new EventListener () { // create an EventListener instance to add
                        public void onEvent (Event event) { // the method will be called while onClick event triggered
                            Clients.evalJavaScript("zk.log('"+tab+"  clicked')");
                            toSel.setSelected(true); // make sure the third one is selected at server side
                        }
                    }
                );
                tab.setWidgetOverride("_sel", "function(notify, init) {return;}"); // prevent select at client side
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use tab#setDisabled(true) then I am not able to fire any event on clicking on any tab.Actually I want to show the info message on clicking any tab without opening that tab

Comment: Solution is good but I have to do this work in java class not in zul page.Is there any way to do task in same way as you have mentioned here.

Comment: Benbai can you tell me how to Remove event Listener from selected tab.I have posted this issue here but not getting proper answer.